# Alter 1 Long Horizontal Block into Vertical Block

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to be able to print a long list into 1 block in a column (Column G line 8 for example):

The given list:

`1 bag of fish 2 bag of fish 3 bag of fish 4 bag of fish 5 bag of fish`

In my excel block it will look as printed above in 1 long horizontal line (but it will be considered in Column G line 8).

How do I alter that block so that it can look like this:

```
1 bag of fish
2 bag of fish
3 bag of fish
4 bag of fish
5 bag of fish
```

but without extending to line 6, 7, 8 etc..

Any advise would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a solution! In the 'Home' selection on Microsoft Excel there is a widget called 'Wrap Text'.

Highlight the block you want 'wrapped' and it will do just that! Hope this helps others!